# Mobile app build and release pipeline workflow in azure devops

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-pipelines

I am not able to set up a workflow or strategy to my project in Azure Devops.
Here is my project structure.

I have two targets in xcode proj and each target has 4 configuration (dev, qa, demo, prod) env set up.

**Taget1** - configurations (dev, qa, demo, prod) pointing each backend
    env url and settings.

**Taget2** - configurations (dev, qa, demo, prod)

How I would create build and release pipelines strategy ?
Requirement is on each PR code should build but that can target to Target1 with any Configuration thats fine. 
But actually challenge in Release pipeline for each target and configuration to release it to Internal QA, Beta Test and Stores.

I am not able to design this, can anyone help me here or give some clue.

Comment: Hi friend, can [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318284/azure-piplines-configuration-for-xcode-managed-profile-setup-possible-documen) give you some hints? Normally you only need one pipeline for build and one for release.

Comment: Thanks for comment actually the above issue is about signing different targets. My problem is after archiving/build how I would set up release each configuration( dev,qa, demo and prod) to different distribution groups in app center like Internal testers, beta testers and prod. How to design or build this process in Azure devops.

Comment: Not sure if this [old document](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/appcenter/) helps. But as I know, if you have multiple configuration. You can consider #1:One agent job with multiple build/test/deploy tasks  #2: One stage with multiple agent jobs. 3.One release pipeline with multiple stages. You can choose one depending on your needs.

Comment: I am looking some example for azure devops build and release pipeline, but above it shows app center example.

Comment: Per my experience, if you want to deploy sth to different environment, now you need different stages in release...